# Add constraint to multiple columns only if one of them is true

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, constraints

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    modified_date DATE NOT NULL,
    is_relevant BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    more columns...
);
```

I have a table of users, and I save history on users. when data on a user is updated, I insert a new row, with the modified date, with the same `user_id`, but with `is_relevant` true. Only the last updated one is with true on `is_relevant`. So each update a user has, I update the prev row to false and insert a new row with true.

I want to add a constraint for a unique key on `user_id` and `is_relevant`, only if `is_relevant` is true. I want to avoid a situation of two rows with the same user id, and true in `is_relevant`.

Comment: " I insert a new row, with the modified date, with the same user_id, but with is_relevant true. Only the last updated one is with true on is_relevant. So each update a user has, I update the prev row to false, and insert new row with true." - **this is not how to design a database** - if you want that model then you should be using Temporal Tables which is supported by most ISO SQL-compliant RDMBS. PostgreSQL has a pattern: https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/6/64/Fosdem20150130PostgresqlTemporal.pdf

Comment: Consider to create a view that only returns the latest row for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a partial unique index, e.g.:

```
create unique index on "user" (user_id) where is_relevant;
```

Read about partial indexes in [the docs.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)